# Averaging results from different experiments where errors may be underestimated

Tags: error, weighted-mean

Let's say we have three different published results that measure the same physical quantity $x$ using completely different methods. Experiment 1 says $x=100\pm0.1$, Experiment 2 says $x=102\pm0.2$, and Experiment 3 says $x=99\pm0.3$. Obviously these results are inconsistent, and we suspect that all three experimenters have underestimated their errors.

Is there any rigorous way to average together these three numbers an get a sensible answer for the error of the mean? I would think the answer is no and the only way to deal with it would be to scale all three errors by some ad-hoc factor to make the results more sensible.

What I would like from a "sensible" procedure is that we acknowledge that the error in experiment 1 is likely greater than 0.1, but it is still likely that experiment 1 is the most precise experiment, and experiment 3 is the least precise.

Like I said, it seems kind of hopeless, the only reason I'm asking is because [wikipedia seems to suggest that there is a solution to exactly this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Correcting_for_over-_or_under-dispersion). However the wikipedia article doesn't provide any references or any justification for the formula it gives. It says you should compute the mean in the normal way (weighted by $1/\sigma^2$) and that the error on the mean is $$\sigma_{\bar{x}}^2 = \frac{ 1 }{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{-2}} \times \frac{1}{(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ (x_i - \bar{x} )^2}{ \sigma_i^2 } .$$

So my question is: what is the source of this formula? Does it apply to the situation I described above?

Comment: The formula seems like the variance of a weighed mean, where weights are the corresponding standard deviations: $var \frac{1}{w_1 + w_2 + w_3}(w_1 X_1 + w_2 X_2 + w_3 X_3)$ where $w_i = \sigma_i$.  It seems a reasonable approach if $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ genuinely have the same value, and the relative size of the corresponding $\sigma$-s is right.

Comment: I think you need more information, and based on that to make a model of your problem.  What are the "experiments"?  Are they measuring genuinely the same object or may the objects, in fact, be different?  What are "errors"?  Are these some sort of variances, or another kind of measurement errors?  Can we assume the "underestimated" or excluded error components are independent?

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand the formula though. I guess it makes sense that $(x_i-\bar{x})^2$ is the best estimate of the variance, but where does the (n-1) come from?

Comment: The experiments measure the same thing, a physical constant like the speed of light, just using different methods. There are going to be many sources of measurement error in the same experiment. They could come from a miscalibration or finite resolution of your instrument, or Poisson statistics, or a variability in temperature over the length of the experiment, etc. Most experiments aren't overly concerned with precision, so all the errors are just folded into one number (or two: statistical error and systematic error), which we assume is nicely Gaussian, even if it isn't really.

Comment: $n-1$ is the "degrees of freedom", typically related to the fact that $\bar x$ is estimated based on the same data.  But I have admit I don't understand the model in wikipedia well.

Comment: Section 11.1 in Robinson and Bevington "Data Reduction and Error Analysis in the Physical Sciences" 2003 discusses using the reduced chi-square for a goodness of fit test. In Wikipedia they use the test backwards to adjust the observed variances to give population variances that will pass the test perfectly.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! This is what I thought what was going on at first, but when I tried to calculate the chi^2 with the new sigma, it still didn't end up being 1.

Comment: @Thomas Oh of course this works. My mistake. I was trying to calculate the chi^2 using the new $\sigma_{\bar{x}}$, whereas I should have been using the scaled errors on the individual data points $\chi_\nu \sigma_i$. Of course using the latter, I get a reduced chi^2 of 1.

Comment: Check out Section 6 in:
Hill, T. P. (2009). Conflations of Probability Distributions. Trans. Amer. Math Soc., 25 May https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0808.1808

Answer (score 1):

A quantity $x$ is measured in three different ways, where $x$ is constant and independent of the measurement.  Experiments are subject to 2 sources of errors and the measurements record instead $$X_i = x + \epsilon_i + \mu_i.$$  The experimenters only know about $\epsilon$ and can come up with a corresponding error estimate $\sigma_i$.

Obviously, unless you know/assume more about $\mu$, you cannot say anything further.  But assume all $\mu_i$ are realizations of the same RV $\mu$ with mean 0, variance $s^2$ and $\mu \perp \epsilon$.

A simple estimator for $x$ is simply an average over $X_i$: $$\hat x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i.$$  (you can come up with variance minimizing estimators as well.)  You can easily see that the value you are looking for, $var\ \hat x$ is $$var\ \hat x = \frac{1}{n^2}\left( \sum_i \sigma_i + n s^2 \right).$$ For unknown $s^2$ you can use the relationship $$var\ X = \sum_i \sigma_i^2 + ns^2.$$

- If you think it makes sense, I can think further but it will take some time.
- Think if you are happy with the assumptions.
- Try it with Monte-Carlo simulations.  I am afraid 3 measurements is way too little to provide anything useful.

Comment: I think this is a good model. It could even be extended. The situation I'm dealing with is that there are actually several different, but related, quantities (e.g. the speed of sound at several different temperatures), but each quantity is measured independently three times (speed at temp X is measured three times, speed at temp Y is measured three times, etc). In my case, it's fairly reasonable to assume that the "unknown error" $\mu$ is actually the same not only for measurements of the same quantity, but also for measurements of the different but related quantity. I'll think about this more